# Returning an interface to a generic with the interface restriction applied

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I'm a bit confused why i can't return my interface type to my generic variable when it is restricted to that interface type.

Here is what i have setup for my generics:

```
public class Graph<T, T2> 
    where T : ISegment 
    where T2 : INode
```

In this class i have the following lines:

```
T2 currNode = GetCurrentNode();
T segment = GetSegment();
T2 otherNode = segment.OtherNode(currNode);
```

My segment interface `ISegment` has the following definition for `OtherNode(INode)`

```
INode OtherNode(INode node);
```

Since I have put `where T2 : INode` for my class how come it gives me an error that says:

> Cannot convert INode to T2

shouldn't this implicitly convert since I restricted my generic `T2` to the interface `INode`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> shouldn't this implicitly convert since I restricted my generic `T2` to the interface `INode`?

That allows the opposite conversion, from `T2` to `INode`. As you can see in `segment.OtherNode(currNode)`, `currNode` is of type `T2`, and `OtherNode` accepts an `INode`.

The `T2 : INode` constraint doesn't mean `T2` must be exactly the same as `INode`. It allows `T2` to be any type that implements `INode`. This means that `T2` could be *any* implementation of `INode`, let's say in this case it's this `MyCoolNode` class that I wrote, which `OtherNode` doesn't know about. Now the line basically says:

```
 MyCoolNode otherNode = segment.OtherNode(currNode);
```

`OtherNode` can't possibly return an instance of `MyCoolNode`! How would the assignment ever make sense?

To fix this, you can constrain `T`, the type of segment, more. You can say that the segment must be a segment connecting nodes of type `T2`. This would  mean making `ISegment` generic:

```
public interface ISegment<TNode> where TNode: INode {
    TNode OtherNode(TNode node);
    ...
}

public class Graph<T, T2> 
    where T : ISegment<T2>
    where T2 : INode
```

Comment: So is this the more streamlined way to do it because the only other fix i found was to do an explicit (T2) cast when returning other node. I presume my explicit cast is slow or has issues i am not aware of..

Comment: Casting to `T2` will crash at runtime if `OtherNode` doesn't return the correct type. If you constrain to `ISegment<T2>` instead, you can't even use a segment type that returns the wrong node type in the first place. The compiler would complain if you do. @WDUK

Comment: Hmm this is confusing as its still telling me to cast. Where my `INode` interface now has a list of `List<ISegments<INode>>();` when i try to get an element and assign to `T` in the class it says it cannot convert but an explicit cast exists.

`Cannot convert ISegment<INode> to "T"`

Not sure how to fix that. Do i have to change my INode interface to be generic aswell some how ? This is how it looks its pretty bare bones: https://imgur.com/3T4HhH8

Comment: @WDUK So your nodes also knows about the segments to which they are connected? I'm not sure whether putting generics on `ISegment` is a good idea then, or maybe your nodes _shouldn't_ know about the segments. Either way, this seems like another problem, a design problem. It is quite hard to tell you what the best design is without knowing what you are actually doing with your graph. Consider asking a new, more detailed question with more context.

Comment: Well its just a way point graph but my segments needed to be polymorphic since they might represent curves or straight lines so they are different geometric objects. My nodes were an interface because i wanted to represent any 3D mesh object as a node in my graph.